# Why kubernetes usually use 3 control-planes and 3 workers?

Tags: kubernetes, architecture

when i google about k8s architecture, many cases use 3 control-planes and 3 workers.

but i have a wonder: why do they use 3 control-planes?

for example, if a cluster has 3 control-plane and 1 control-plane(work as a master) is dropped, control-planes which are working is two. but 2 control-planes cannot elect a leader, and cluster cannot be restored from disaster. that is not fail-over system.

but many usecases says "use 3 control-planes". why number of control-planes should be odd?

Comment: It's a restriction imposed by [etcd](https://etcd.io/docs/v3.5/faq/#why-an-odd-number-of-cluster-members), so in that way it's not actually a restriction of the k8s control-plane, it's just that **a lot** of hello-world clusters deploy in so-called "stacked" setup, where each apiserver Node also carries an etcd member

Comment: Why wouldn't the two remaining nodes be able to elect a leader? They can still achieve majority.